# Minkowski inequality for vector valued function

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces

There are plenty of resources on Minkowski inequality. For example, this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

My question is, is there a Minkowski inequality for vector valued functions $f$ and $g$? Specifically, when $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both $m$-dimensional vectors, would the following hold

$\|f+g\|_p \leq \|f\|_p + \|g\|_p$, where $\|f\|_p = \left(\int \|f(x)\|_p^p dx\right)^{1\over p}$ and $\|f(x)\|_p$ is vector's $p$-norm.

Comment: Yes, it is true even for Banach space valued (Bochner) integrals.

Comment: Is there a suggested lecture note?